# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html error in console

Tags: html, css, mime-types

I am trying to include flexslider in my Angular App and getting a following error  after i included the flexslider css file

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/controlpanel/users/css/style.css".
```

I checked to see if my file location was not correct but it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is not serving the resource using the correct `Content-Type` in the HTTP header.  Your web server should have a setting for MIME types by file extensions, but that depends what server you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue. Well, I was just trying to use a servlet to load welcome jsp page, which contains a .css file in header.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
</head>
```

And I got the same error "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/webapp/css/style.css"

When I used developer tools in chrome, under 'Network' tab, two calls were made when hit my webapp's landing url "http://localhost:8080/webapp/"

I changed my default servlet url from "/" to "/index" in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NextServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then added "./" to href,

```
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/base.css">
</head>
```

It worked.